# Inserting Data from XML nodes into Database via SSIS

Tags: sql, xml, web-services, ssis

I want to insert the below XML Data retrieved from web service task into my Database,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Name xmlns="http://Iycon.com/WebService">Rahul</Name>
 <BirthDate xmlns="http://Iycon.com/WebService">1988-09-23T00:00:00</BirthDate>
</Data>,
```

I am making use of foreach loop container to loop through different nodes but unable to get the result, this data I am inserting into database via Execute SQL Task, I have tried lot but unable to find solution,Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following to get the data into SQL Server.

1. Add Webservice Task
   This retrieves the complete node set from the web service. 
       Update a variable(object) with the web service response data.
2. Add Data Flow Control
3. Add XML Source Control
   Use XML from variable and generate the XSD
4. Add OLE Destination Control
   Map your columns to match the XML nodes exposed from the XML Source.

Comment: Thanks, actually I have already solved this solution in the way you have explained earlier and was unable to close this question but still I am thinking your answer can be useful to others who will come across this question. The above said method works correctly.